# Algorithm implemented in ruby to add one to a number represented as an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

I need advice on my ruby based solution to a problem on Interviewbit. The problem is as follows

```
Given a non-negative number represented as an array of digits,

add 1 to the number ( increment the number represented by the digits ).

The digits are stored such that the most significant digit is at the head of the list. There can be upto 10,000 digits in the input array.

Example:

If the vector has [1, 2, 3]

the returned vector should be [1, 2, 4]

as 123 + 1 = 124.
```

My first solution was as follows

```
 def plusOne(a)
        new_number = a.join.to_i + 1
        result = []
        while new_number > 0
            result.push new_number%10
            new_number /= 10
        end
        result.reverse
 end
```

This algorithm seems correct, it passed the test inputs but on submission it gives a 'Time Limit Exceeded'. My second solution was a successful submission and is as follows.

```
def plusOne(a)
      carry = 1
      start_index = a.size - 1
      temp_result = []
      ans = []

      for i in start_index.downto(0)
            sum = a[i] + carry
            carry = sum/10
            temp_result.push sum%10
      end
      temp_result.push carry

      start_index = temp_result.size - 1
      while start_index >= 0 and temp_result[start_index] == 0
          start_index -= 1
      end

      while start_index >= 0
          ans.push temp_result[start_index]
          start_index -= 1
      end
      ans
    end
```

My first solution seems to be O(n) to me as we are just iterating over the digits in the number. So, can someone please tell me why it could have exceeded the time limit ?

Thank You

Comment: @JörgWMittag : Note that `Integer#digits` returns the least significant digit at the head of the array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while new_number > 0
    result.push new_number%10
    new_number /= 10
end
```

Even though at first glance this loop seems to be `O(n)`, it is at least `Ω(n²)`.

Since big numbers in Ruby are stored and processed as arrays of binary digits (digits in base 2³²), division by `10` is a costly operation. The exact time complexity depends on the division algorithm Ruby uses, but `new_number /= 10` will have to process all of the `new_number`'s binary digits, so it cannot be faster than `O(n)`.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the explanation. I was suprised to notice the while loop being so slow.

Comment: You can avoid reversing the array at the end by replacing `push` with `unshift`. You might also speed this up by using [Integer#divmod](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.3.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-divmod): `new_number = 123; result = []; while new_number > 0; new_number, remainder = new_number.divmod(10); result.unshift(remainder); end; result #=> [1,2,3]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: `unshift` is slower than `push`, so you don't gain any time by doing so. `divmod` appears to be twice as fast as `new_number /= 10`

Answer (score 3):

## Solution

Note that O(n) should be your worst case scenario (e.g. with `[9]*n`).

For `[1,2,3]*1000`, the operation can be done in 1 step, since there's no carry and you'd just need to calculate `3+1`.

In your first method, the `while` loop seems to be very expensive.

Just using :

```
(a.join.to_i+1).to_s.chars.map{|i| i.to_i}
```

is much faster, according to [fruity](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity).

## Faster solution

if it's acceptable to modify the original array :

```
class Solution
  # param a : array of integers
  # return a array of integers
  def plusOne(a)
    a.unshift(0)
    carry = 1
    (a.size-1).downto(0) do |index|
      if a[index] < 9
        a[index] += carry
        break
      else
        a[index] = 0
      end
    end
    a.shift while a[0] == 0
    a
  end
end
```

It passed the test on [www.interviewbit.com](https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/add-one-to-number/), and fruity tells me it's 45 times faster than your second method and 180 times faster than your first one.

Comment: Have you benchmarked `(a.join.to_i + 1).digits` also for comparison?

Comment: Yes, it's **really** slow. It also returns the digits in the reversed order. For `[9] * 10000`, `(a.join.to_i+1).to_s.chars.map{|i| i.to_i}` is 13 times faster than `(a.join.to_i+1).digits.reverse`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_1(arr)
  idx = arr.rindex { |n| n < 9 }
  return [1].concat([0]*arr.size) if idx.nil?
  arr.map.with_index do |n,i|
    case i <=> idx
    when -1 then n
    when 0 then n+1
    else 0
    end
  end
end

add_1 [1, 2, 3]
  #=> [1, 2, 4] 
add_1 [1, 2, 9]
  #=> [1, 3, 0] 
add_1 [1, 9, 9]
  #=> [2, 0, 0] 
add_1 [9, 9, 9]
  #=> [1, 0, 0, 0]
```

This could also be written

```
def add_1(arr)
  idx = arr.rindex { |n| n < 9 }
  return [1].concat([0]*arr.size) if idx.nil?
  (arr[0,idx] << arr[idx]+1).concat([0]*(arr.size-idx-1))
end
```

which may be more efficient.

Comment: It works fine, but fruity tells me it's about 100x times slower than my code for `a = [1,2,3] * 100` or `a = [9] * 1000`

Comment: @Eric, I added an alternative that may be more efficient, but when comparing efficiency note that I've not mutated the original array. Of the two I think the former reads better, and may well be acceptable efficiency-wise.